# Converting seconds to HH:MM:SS in Crystal Reports graph

Tags: graph, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a custom query that returns this recordset:

```
Name     Time     Time_HHMMSS
Bill      121        00:02:01
Julie     48         00:00:48
```

etc.

I want a bar graph in the report header that has Time_HHMMS on the Y axis and Name on the x axis. However, the chart engine in Crystal is limited so it doesn't seem you can do that easily. How to accomplish? (using Crystal Reports 2008)

Thanks!

Comment: How are you populating the graph?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking--the data is given above. Just want a simple graph, but I want to use the Time_HHMMSS field instead of the "Time" field.

Comment: What I want to know if you're pulling the data from database? Or the example you're showing above is all the data you use?

Comment: Just those 3 fields are pulled from the query. The data from the query is as given, that is not after any manipulation in Crystal.